# Salesforce marketing cloud api - package manager

Tags: cloud, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a question about marketing cloud API - is there an API for package manager. To create a package (of assets, data extensions, landing pages etc.) using the API.

I am aware of Content builder API to get Email assets, and there is API available to get data extension & their field names. But a single API to execute a package creation say every night to backup all important assets in sfmc.

Recently had a spate of incidents where some assets were accidently deleted from marketing cloud business unit.

Any help/tips will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no API available for package manager. You can only operate it through the UI.